# Access named tuple by string?

Tags: c#

How to get an item from a tuple based on the name of that item in a string?

```cs
var tuple = (name: "Voltrax", age: 34);
var item = "name";
tuple[item] // should be "Voltrax"
```

Comment: The way you are going about this, wheter its a tuple or struct or obj, is *going* to require reflection. To be be clear, do you need to access the field directly like `tuple.name` or do you need to be able to dynamically access a field from a string for the field's name? The 2nd route is much more complex

Comment: @Narish the second way

Comment: The name for an Item in a tuple is a compile time feature it does not exist in the compiled code. In the compiled code you will find them replaced by the predefined names on those positions. So you can see only Item1 either directly or via reflection. But "name" does not exist anymore. If you want something that gives you a value for a string use a dictionary instead of  a tuple.

Comment: Maybe it will suit you to access the elements of the tuple by index through the [ITuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.ituple?view=net-6.0) interface?

Comment: Use dictionary for such cases, not tuples